Why is the DWM status bar not getting mic info?
I don't really get why the mic status via icon isn't working on DWM:
Status script
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Log file path
LOGFILE="$HOME/.cache/dwm_status.log"

# Initialize
printf "$$" > ~/.cache/pidofbar
sec=0

# Function to fetch CPU load average
update_cpu() {
  cpu=$(awk '{print $1}' /proc/loadavg)
}

# Function to fetch used memory
update_memory() {
  memory=$(free -h | awk 'NR==2 {print $3}')
}

# Function to fetch current time in Asia/Dhaka timezone
update_time() {
  time=$(TZ='Asia/Dhaka' date +"%I:%M %p %a %b %d, %Y")
}

# Function to fetch current weather in Dhaka using wttr.in
update_weather() {
  weather=$(curl -s "https://wttr.in/dhaka?format=2" | awk '{gsub(/   /, " "); print}')
}

# Function to fetch battery status and capacity
update_bat() {
  if [ -e /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status ]; then
    bat_status=$(< /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status)
    bat_capacity=$(< /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity)
    case $bat_capacity in
      100|9[0-9]|8[0-9]) bat_icon=" " ;;
      7[0-9]|6[0-9]) bat_icon=" " ;;
      5[0-9]|4[0-9]) bat_icon=" " ;;
      3[0-9]|2[0-9]) bat_icon=" " ;;
      1[0-9]|[0-9]) bat_icon=" " ;;
    esac
    if [ "$bat_status" = "Charging" ]; then
      bat=" $bat_icon $bat_capacity%"
    else
      bat=" $bat_icon $bat_capacity%"
    fi
  else
    bat="Battery status unavailable"
  fi
}

# Function to fetch volume information and mute status
update_vol() {
  vol_info=$(pactl list sinks | awk '
    /^Sink / { sink = $2 }
    /State: RUNNING/ { running_sink = sink }
    $1 == "Volume:" {
      volumes[sink] = $5
      if (sink == running_sink) {
        running_volume = $5
      }
    }
    $1 == "Mute:" {
      mutes[sink] = $2
      if (sink == running_sink) {
        running_mute = $2
      }
    }
    END {
      if (running_sink) {
        if (running_mute == "yes" || running_volume == "0%") {
          print ""  # Muted icon
        } else {
          print running_volume
        }
      } else {
        for (sink in volumes) {
          if (volumes[sink] != "100%") {
            if (mutes[sink] == "yes" || volumes[sink] == "0%") {
              print ""  # Muted icon
            } else {
              print volumes[sink]
            }
            exit
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ')

  if [ "$vol_info" = "" ]; then
    vol=""
  else
    volume_percentage="${vol_info%\%}"
    if [ "$volume_percentage" -ge 75 ]; then
      vol=" $vol_info"  # High volume icon
    elif [ "$volume_percentage" -ge 50 ]; then
      vol=" $vol_info"  # Medium volume icon
    elif [ "$volume_percentage" -ge 25 ]; then
      vol=" $vol_info"  # Low volume icon
    else
      vol=" $vol_info"  # Very low volume icon
    fi
  fi
}

# Function to fetch microphone mute status using stmictst script's logic
update_mic() {
  mic_info=$(bash stmictst | awk '/Mic1|Mic2/ {print $NF}')

  if [ "$mic_info" = "muted" ]; then
    mic=""
  else
    mic=""
  fi
}

# Function to fetch current backlight status
update_backlight() {
  if [ -e /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness ]; then
    actual_brightness=$(cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness)
    max_brightness=$(cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness)
    backlight="☀$((actual_brightness * 100 / max_brightness))%"
    echo "Actual brightness: $actual_brightness, Max brightness: $max_brightness, Calculated backlight: $backlight" >> $LOGFILE
  else
    backlight="Backlight not available"
    echo "Backlight not available" >> $LOGFILE
  fi
}

# Function to display status on dwm
display() {
  status=""
  [ -n "$cpu" ] && status+="CPU: $cpu "
  [ -n "$memory" ] && status+="Mem: $memory "
  [ -n "$weather" ] && status+="$weather "
  [ -n "$bat" ] && status+="$bat "
  [ -n "$backlight" ] && status+="$backlight "
  [ -n "$vol" ] && status+="$vol "
  [ -n "$mic" ] && status+="$mic " 
  [ -n "$time" ] && status+="$time"
  echo "Setting status: $status" >> $LOGFILE  # Debug output
  xsetroot -name "$status"
}

# Signal handlers for updating specific parts of status
trap "update_vol; display" "RTMIN"
trap "update_backlight; display" "RTMIN+1"
trap "update_bat; display" "RTMIN+2"
trap "update_mic; display" "RTMIN+3"

# Initial updates
update_cpu
update_memory
update_time
update_weather
update_bat
update_backlight
update_vol
update_mic

# Initial display
display

# Main loop to continuously update and display status
while true; do
  sleep 1
  sec=$((sec + 1))
  case $((sec % 60)) in
    0) 
      update_bat
      update_backlight
      ;;
    5|10|15|20|25|30|35|40|45|50|55)

      update_cpu
      update_memory
      ;;
  esac

  # Update weather every 8 hours
  if [ $((sec % 3600)) -eq 0 ]; then
    update_weather
  fi

  update_vol
  update_time
  update_mic
  display
done

Mic status script
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Function to check if a source is muted
# Usage: is_muted SOURCE_INFO
is_muted() {
    local source_info="$1"
    # Check if Mute: yes is present in the source info
    if echo "$source_info" | grep -q "Mute: yes"; then
        echo "muted"
    else
        echo "unmuted"
    fi
}

# Function to get the microphone status based on headphone connection
get_microphone_status() {
    local pactl_output="$1"

    # Check if headphone is connected
    if echo "$pactl_output" | grep -q "HiFi__Headphones__sink"; then
        # Headphone is connected, check microphone status for Mic2
        mic_status=$(is_muted "$(echo "$pactl_output" | awk '/HiFi__Mic2__source/,/^$/')")
        echo "Headphone Mic (Mic2) is $mic_status"
    else
        # Headphone is not connected, check microphone status for Mic1
        mic_status=$(is_muted "$(echo "$pactl_output" | awk '/HiFi__Mic1__source/,/^$/')")
        echo "Laptop Mic (Mic1) is $mic_status"
    fi
}

# Fetch pactl output and pass it to get_microphone_status function
pactl_output=$(pactl list sources)

# Call function to get microphone status
get_microphone_status "$pactl_output"

The relevant configs are in here.

A way to debug this would be to try out the relevant parts of stmictst and see what they output.
